# Django module to transform data from database to be displayed in Slickgrid tables

Tags: python, pandas, django

This is a Django tag with 2 classes, but can be viewed as a module:

**What does the module do?** it loads a database, performs some transformations on the data, returns the output as a dictionary of json strings for the frontend of django to represent in slickgrid tables

It's all working fine, but my class is too abstract and ended using a lot of static methods because there is actually no state that I need.

This first class shouldn't be important, don't think there is something here to improve. I basically have 4 types in 3 categories and want to go from 4 pandas dataframes to 12 json strings that are passed to django frontend:

```
class RenderTag:

    @staticmethod
    def get_context_data():

        annotations = Annotations()
        df_type_1_category_1, df_type_1_category_2, df_type_1_category_3 = annotations.filter_categories(annotations.df_type_1)
        df_type_2_category_1, df_type_2_category_2, df_type_2_category_3 = annotations.filter_categories(annotations.df_type_2)
        df_type_3_category_1, df_type_3_category_2, df_type_3_category_3 = annotations.filter_categories(annotations.df_type_3)
        df_type_4_category_1, df_type_4_category_2, df_type_4_category_3 = annotations.filter_categories(annotations.df_type_4)

        # json data for js tables
        json_for_category_1_1 = df_type_1_category_1.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
        json_for_category_1_2 = df_type_2_category_1.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
        json_for_category_1_3 = df_type_3_category_1.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
        json_for_category_1_4 = df_type_4_category_1.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
        json_for_category_2_1 = df_type_1_category_2.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
        json_for_category_2_2 = df_type_2_category_2.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
        json_for_category_2_3 = df_type_3_category_2.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
        json_for_category_2_4 = df_type_4_category_2.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
        json_for_category_3_1 = df_type_1_category_3.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
        json_for_category_3_2 = df_type_2_category_3.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
        json_for_category_3_3 = df_type_3_category_3.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
        json_for_category_3_4 = df_type_4_category_3.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)

        context = {
            "json_1_1": json_for_category_1_1.to_json(orient='split'),
            "json_1_2": json_for_category_1_2.to_json(orient='split'),
            "json_1_3": json_for_category_1_3.to_json(orient='split'),
            "json_1_4": json_for_category_1_4.to_json(orient='split'),
            "json_2_1": json_for_category_2_1.to_json(orient='split'),
            "json_2_2": json_for_category_2_2.to_json(orient='split'),
            "json_2_3": json_for_category_2_3.to_json(orient='split'),
            "json_2_4": json_for_category_2_4.to_json(orient='split'),
            "json_3_1": json_for_category_3_1.to_json(orient='split'),
            "json_3_2": json_for_category_3_2.to_json(orient='split'),
            "json_3_3": json_for_category_3_3.to_json(orient='split'),
            "json_3_4": json_for_category_3_4.to_json(orient='split'),
        }

        return context
```

This class I think needs a lot of improvement:

```
class Annotations:

    def __init__(self):

        # loading data
        self.df_type_2 = helpers.load_database("type_2").round(2)
        self.df_type_3 = helpers.load_database("type_3").round(2)
        self.df_type_1 = helpers.load_database("type_1").round(2)

        # main transformations

        # type_2 and 4
        self.df_type_2, self.df_type_4 = self.split_2_into_2_and_4(self.df_type_2)
        self.df_type_4 = self.do_transformations_for_4(self.df_type_4)
        self.df_type_2 = self.do_transformations_for_2(self.df_type_2)

        # type_1
        self.df_type_1 = self.do_transformations_for_1(self.df_type_1)

        # type_3
        self.df_type_3 = self.do_transformations_for_3(self.df_type_3)

# and I have 4 methods that call a lot of static functions    

    def do_transformations_for_1(self, df):
        """
        This is the main function that edits the data for type 1
            We take the main df and then we run a series of manipulations

        Args:
            df(pd.DataFrame): the df that we want to process

        Returns:
            df(pd.DataFrame): the end dataframe that will be transferred to the js file
        """
        df["id"] = df.index
        df = df.pipe(self.do_something)\
                .pipe(self.do_something_1)\
                .pipe(self.do_something_2)\
                .pipe(self.do_something_3)\
                .pipe(self.do_something_4)\
                .pipe(self.do_something_5)\
                .pipe(self.add_colors_log2foldchange)\
                .pipe(self.fill_na_with_empty_strings)\
                .pipe(helpers.sort_df_by_columns, self.columns_to_sort_snv)

        return df

    def do_transformations_for_2(self, df):
        """
        This is a function that runs only for type 2
            We take the main df and then we run a series of manipulations

        Args:
            df(pd.DataFrame): the df that we want to process

        Returns:
            df(pd.DataFrame): the end dataframe that will be transferred to the js file
        """
        df = df.pipe(self.do_something) \
                .pipe(self.add_colors_log2foldchange) \
                .pipe(self.do_something_7)\
                .pipe(helpers.sort_df_by_columns, self.columns_to_sort_type_4)\

        return df

    def do_transformations_for_3(self, df):
        """
        This is a function that runs only for type 3. We take the main df and then we run a series of manipulations

        Args:
            df(pd.DataFrame): the df that we want to process

        Returns:
            df(pd.DataFrame): the end dataframe that will be transferred to the js file
        """
        df = df.pipe(self.do_something, False) \
                .pipe(self.do_something_9) \
                .pipe(self.add_colors_log2foldchange) \
                .pipe(helpers.sort_df_by_columns, self.columns_to_sort_type_3)

        return df

    def do_transformations_for_4(self, df):
        """
        This is a function that runs only for the type_4 
            We take the main df and then we run a series of manipulations

        Args:
            df(pd.DataFrame): the df that we want to process

        Returns:
            df(pd.DataFrame): the end dataframe that will be transferred to the js file
        """
        df = df.pipe(self.do_something, True) \
                .pipe(self.do_something_9) \
                .pipe(self.add_colors_log2foldchange) \
                .pipe(helpers.sort_df_by_columns, self.columns_to_sort_type_2)

        return df

# many static methods that are only used once or twice, deleted many of them


    @staticmethod
    def unicode_lists_to_string(df, columns):
        for column in columns:
            df[column] = df[column].str.strip("[]").str.replace("u'|'",'').str.replace(",",";")

        return df

    @staticmethod
    def transform_type_4_position(df: pd.DataFrame):
        """
        Remove copy number from position in type_4 table and also add chr in front

        Args:
            df(pd.DataFrame):

        Returns:
            pd.DataFrame: with position modified
        """
        df["vid_position"] = "chr" + df["vid"].str.split(":").str[:3].str.join(":")

        return df

    @staticmethod
    def filter_categories(df):
        """
        Split the df by categories because we want them in separate tables

        Args:
            df: main df

        Returns:
            Tuple[pd.DataFrame]: a tuple of 3 dataframes from categories 1,2,3

        """
        df_1 = df[df["category"] == 1]
        df_2 = df[df["category"] == 2]
        df_3 = df[df["category"] == 3]

        return df_1, df_2, df_3

    @staticmethod
    def add_colors_log2foldchange(df: pd.DataFrame):
        """
        We want to add background colors to log2foldchange values, fron blue to red

        Args:
            df(pd.DataFrame): df with log2foldchange values

        Returns:
            df(pd.DataFrame): df with a new hex_color column
        """
        df_new = helpers.add_colors_to_df(df, helpers.get_colors(), "log2_fold_change")
        df_new["hex_color"] = df_new["hex_color"].str.replace("#", "")

        return df_new

    @staticmethod
    def edit_support_alt_ref(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """

        Args:
            df(pd.DataFrame):

        Returns:
            pd.DataFrame:
        """
        def strip_germline_from_alt_ref(row):
            if pd.notna(row):
                if "]," in row:
                    row = row.split("],")
                    row = row[1]

                row = row.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "|").replace(" ", "")

            return row

        df["paired_end_reads"] = df["paired_end_reads"].apply(strip_germline_from_alt_ref)
        df["split_end_reads"] = df["split_end_reads"].apply(strip_germline_from_alt_ref)

        return df
```

As you can see I do modifications for all 4 types in 4 methods.

I think I can go along with not using a class here, but sort of want to use a class here to be inline with the whole project... I use static methods because they are obviously easier to unit test. Pass a df and return a df, easy unit test.

Answer (score 3):

> This first class shouldn't be important, don't think there is something here to improve.

You're wrong :)

There's a sea of repeated code here. You need to seriously DRY it up. I don't have enough of your system to test this myself, so you need to; but you should do something like

```
class RenderTag:
    @staticmethod
    def get_context_data():
        annotations = Annotations()

        def to_json(x):
            return x.to_json()

        context = {}
        for i in range(1, 5):
            df_type = getattr(annotations, f'df_type_{i}')
            categories = annotations.filter_categories(df_type)
            for j, category in enumerate(categories, 1):
                js = category.apply(to_json, axis=1).to_json(orient='split')
                context[f'json{j}_{i}'] = js

        return context
```

That assumes that `Annotations` cannot change. You can make it even simpler if `Annotations.df_type` is stored as a 3-tuple, instead of three separate attributes. Elsewhere in your code, you really should carry this philosophy forward - instead of hard-coding three or four variables with numbers in the name, just maintain one tuple (if immutable) or list (if mutable).